# Fetch is not sending secure cookie during cross domain POST request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, fetch, bottle

I cannot get this fetch request to correctly send the cookie (session id that is successfully stored in the Chrome browsers application tab within cookies). The cookie is a python bottle created, beaker.session.id cookie that is marked secure.

[image]

I have my bottle server configured to deal with CORS requests and cookies with the following headers being returned:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials →true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers →Origin, Accept, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods →PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →http://localhost:3000
```

My javascript code is:

```
 fetch("https://#.#.#.#/session-status", 
    {
        credentials: "include",
        method: "post",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "id": id
        }),
    }).then(res => {
        return res.json()
```

What could be causing this issue? The preflight OPTIONS request succeeds with a 200 OK, but the POST request does not send the necessary headers which include the session id.

Comment: Do you see any CORS errors in your console log? Everything in the network tab can look good, but you can still get errors. Also, should the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header be https instead of http?

Comment: No CORS errors in console logs. The header should be http because I am not using SSL at the moment on the frontend application just the REST interface.

Comment: Does the cookie belong to `http://localhost:3000` or `https://#.#.#.#/`?

Comment: The cookie belongs to https://#.#.#.#/ it is sent and generated from a bottle server running on that host.

Comment: Just tried it with a non "secure" session.id still doesnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE:

Turns out the issue was the SameSite: "Lax" part of the cookie. Bottle by default has SameSite: 'Lax" enabled, but you need to manually set it to None to not send the attribute. SameSite: "Lax" does not allow you to send unsafe requests (example: POST) from another domain according to this [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-first-party-cookies-07) in section 4.3.